# Eclipse wont let my app run

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to install the app I making on my phone. But I keep getting an error

```
Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES
```

I'm using Eclipse. I've never seen this problem before. I have run my app on my phone hundreds of times. No apparent errors exist in any files of my project. I edited the Manifest file upping the version, but it didnt work. I cleaned my project. I uninstalled the current version of my app from my phone. But none of this works.

I have absolutely no idea what the problem is. The LogCat claims it is a problem with my main.xml file.

```
ERROR/PackageParser(956): Package ##MY PACKAGE NAME has no certificates at entry res/layout/main.xml; ignoring!
```

I havent touched this file so I dont know what could be the problem.

UPDATE: Things got more confusing. Before the problem occured I drag-n-dropped a few png files into the drawable folder (where there are already a few). After pulling my hair out it dawned on me the problem might be these files. I deleted them all (5 in total) and it works now. Only problem is I dont know why they screwed up installation.

Comment: Try cleaning the project and rebuilding.

Comment: Did it. Cleaned it, rebuilt it - same problem. Restarted eclipse. tried it again. Same result. I'm baffled.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems to be a fairly common issue: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=830

A workaround is to export an unsigned package and sign it manually with signapk.jar

Verbatim:

> Comment 26 by lucasiturbide, Apr 14,
>   2010 Hi everybody.  I have solved this
>   in my project by signing the APK with
>   the debugkey and the jarsigner tool
>   provided by android tools.
>
> Just execute this:

```
 jarsigner -verbose -keystore <userhome>/.android/debug.keystore <package.apk> androiddebugkey
```

> and you will have your nice fresh and
>   working apk for debugging only
>   purpose. Remember you have to sign
>   your APK with a valid signature to
>   publish your application at the Market

The password for the debug key with the alias "androiddebugkey" is "android".

Comment: This solution also works when specifying your own (non-debug) keystore. Replace `.../debug.keystore` with the path to your own keystore, and `androiddebugkey` with the name of your key. 

Thanks!

Comment: If your `~/.android/debug.keystore` does not exist, there's a command to generate the very specific one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10981870/198348