# generated apk appears corrupted

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

I am trying to generate a correct apk to test it on my phone. Anyway when I try to install it with apk manager it tells me my file is corrupted. So i cannot install . I changed the extension to zip and opened it, and here is what I found :

```
META-INF (folder)
res (folder)
AndroidManifest.xml
classes.dex
resources.arsc
```

My project is very small for the moment, just one class containing a basic mediaplayer.
I opened other APKs and I saw they had more folders.

Here is what I did :
Generation with eclipse : right click on project, Android tools, Export signed application package. Then keystore step.

I checked my app what well signed with the jarsigned command. The CN field returned me the initials I had entered for the keystore so I think this step was good. Any help is welcome :)

PS : I already tried to export my app with Export -> Export Android Application. The apk was also corrupted.

Comment: are you using the debug.keystore or your own keystore?

Comment: My own keystore. I created it.

Comment: try using the debug keystore... if it works, make a new keystore from scratch

Comment: OK does Eclipse use implicit keystore when not the apk is unsigned ? Otherway I'm asked to enter a keystore.

Comment: use debug keystore for debugging. check my answer, i edited it.

Comment: OK when I exported the project I created a new keystore named debug.keystore with password keystore. What it the correct way to do ? 'cause my jar is still corrupted

Comment: no no.. the debug.keystore is created automatically by the Android SDK. You don't need to create it. Only create a keystore file when you are ready to publish the app in the Play Store. For debugging, use debug.keystore that is created automatically by SDK.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I tried with the one in the apk and with a generated one, as shown here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8576732/there-is-no-debug-keystore-in-android-folder -, but the apk is still corrupted

Comment: That is weird. Maybe your android tools are corrupted. If all else fails, try reinstalling Eclipse and Android SDK.

Comment: Well I downloaded Eclipse Android SDK here : http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html as I had always done, and I have the same problems. I will see...

Answer (score 0):

Try using this method:

1. Right-click on the project
2. Export
3. Android>Export Android Application
4. Next > Select your keystore file or create a new one
5. Follow the steps.

**EDIT:**

Try using the debug.keystore which is present at the following places:

Windows: C:\Users\username\.android\debug.keystore

Linux: /home/username/.android/debug.keystore

Comment: I already did that. But I had the same result. I'm gonna add it in the post