# How to work with android studio for import and run project

Tags: java, android, telegram

I had download project from github and I want to import it into android studio. I tried several time but I cant run it. Any one give the step by step instruction to import the project because am new one for android studio.

```
Showing Error:

    "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java" -ea -Didea.launcher.port=7532 -Didea.launcher.bin.path=D:\Users\SYS\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "D:\Users\SYS\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\lib\idea_rt.jar;D:\Users\SYS\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\plugins\junit\lib\junit-rt.jar;D:\Android By Timothy\Package tools\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\platforms\android-21\android.jar;D:\Android By Timothy\Package tools\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\platforms\android-21\data\res;D:\Android By Timothy\Package tools\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\tools\support\annotations.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 @C:\Users\SYS\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_junit7097204602616052537.tmp @w@C:\Users\SYS\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_working_dirs_junit3836436993075423504.tmp -socket54727
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: junit/textui/ResultPrinter
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:260)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:116)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: junit.textui.ResultPrinter
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 3 more

    Process finished with exit code 1
```

Now i got error:

`11:51:25 UnsupportedMethodException
         Failed to set up Android modules in project 'Telegram-master': Unsupported method: SourceProvider.getJniDirectories().
         The version of Gradle you connect to does not support that method.
         To resolve the problem you can change/upgrade the target version of Gradle you connect to.
         Alternatively, you can ignore this exception and read other information from the model.`

Comment: i had try it but non of ths are help me i try the telegram proj from github

Comment: "Any one give the step by step instruction" this is not a school, you have to try and ask any doubt in the code. If you tried add what you did with it.

Comment: @user3634291 if you can describe exactly what the problem was then you are more likely to get an answer

Comment: post the link of Github project.

Comment: Do you have git?

Answer (score 0):

I tried, and here is steps:

1. Git clone the project to you disk
2. Import project on your Android Studio.
3. There was one Error of gradle. Change the gradle version to latest 1.0.0, such that
   "classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
4. Get your own api_id form [here](https://core.telegram.org/api/obtaining_api_id).
5. Follow the [doc](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/blob/master/README.md).

**EDIT**

For `'signingConfig.storeFile' does not exist` problem:

1: Look if you have the debug.keystore in (~/.android or search your whole android folder). If you haven't got it. Look this ([There is no debug.keystore in .android folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8576732/there-is-no-debug-keystore-in-android-folder)) for create a debug.keystore.

2: When you have the file. You have to copy the file('debug.keystore') on (Telegram/TMessagesProj/config).

Comment: Thank u soo much dude i will try it and comment here 1s again thank u

Comment: No problem, it's hard to begin something:）

Comment: How to change Change the gradle version to latest 1.0.0

Comment: what version of your android studio?

Comment: Android Studio (Beta) 0.8.6

Comment: Hi dude now i dowload android stud 1.0.1 and instaled it and import the tele project now i got gradle error missmatch how to fix it

Comment: now i got this error Error:A problem was found with the configuration of task ':TMessagesProj:packageDebug'.
> File 'D:\Studio Projects\Telegram\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\config\debug.keystore' specified for property 'signingConfig.storeFile' does not exist.

Comment: Why down vote? I solve the problem, see the edit in my answer