# Can't locate Mono for Android Folder. Xamarin Android for Maps

Tags: android, xamarin, maps

Can't locate Mono for Android folder inside Xamarin file in C:\Users[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore

Need to it to obtain my signing key fingerprint for android google maps.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Make sure that your path is correct and that you are using the correct `USERNAME` or use `"%LocalAppData%\Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore"` Example:  `keytool.exe -list -v -keystore "%LocalAppData%\Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/MD5_SHA1/

Comment: If you don't have a keystore in that location, you can generate a new one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36554463/lost-my-debug-keystore-due-to-xamarin-new-installation-can-i-recover-it/36554649#36554649

Answer (score 1):

1. Find the `debug.keystore` at the following path for example: `C:\Users\YOURACCOUNT\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android`.
2. Copy this `debug.keystore` into the bin folder of your JDK. For example, I'm using JDK1.8 for Android 7.0, then I need to copy this file to the path: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin`.
3. Open CMD as Administrator.
4. Access to the bin folder of your JDK, by my side it is `cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin`.
5. As @SushiHangover suggested, by my side, I need to execute `keytool.exe -list -v -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`.

The path of your JDK is important here, be sure you have the right path.

Comment: Thanks movement debug.keystore to another folder is simple solution.