# Xamarin APK signing issue

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mono, visual-studio-2017

Even though I have "Sign the .APK file using the following keystore details" checked, and have specified an absolute path to a keystore, I get this in the build output (Had to switch to diagnostic)

`Executing: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\bin\jarsigner.exe -keystore "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android -digestalg SHA1 -sigalg md5withRSA -signedjar "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\dpabsfke.ueg\unaligned.jar" "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\dpabsfke.ueg\unsigned.apk" androiddebugkey`

which results in the following error

`jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore (The system cannot find the file specified)`

And of course, since the `debug.keystore` doesn't exist at that location, unchecking the "Sign the .APK file..." results in a failed debug signing as well.

Has anyone else run into this issue? I'd like to resolve this without having to resort to manually signing my APKs.

Comment: Are you making sure you're using a `Release` configuration?

Comment: `Release` and `Debug` configuration both have the same result.

Comment: You can also generate a debug.keystore with the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36554463/lost-my-debug-keystore-due-to-xamarin-new-installation-can-i-recover-it/36554649#36554649

Comment: I've actually created a `debug.keystore` file by simply creating a new blank project and debugging it in the emulator. Everything appears to be working as intended now. Thanks for the response @JonDouglas

Comment: You may be running into https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/pull/1148

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are running into the following bug:

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=61065

This should be fixed via the following pull request:

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/pull/1148

In the meantime, you will need to ensure the `debug.keystore` is generated locally. I have an answer that can help out in that area:

[Lost my debug.keystore due to Xamarin new installation. Can i recover it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36554463/lost-my-debug-keystore-due-to-xamarin-new-installation-can-i-recover-it/36554649#36554649)