# how to solve this error 'debug.keystore not found inside c:\Users\kulde\.android\' while creating Android Signing Certificate SHA-1

Tags: android

i am trying to create google login app in which i need Android Signing Certificate SHA-1.

At the starting there is .android folder in which contain two other files
    but those are not debug.keystore so i read somewhere on stackoverflow they 
    said delete .android folder its will automatically created when rebuild the 
    project so i did it but it not created any .android folder or debug.keystore

i tried various command its giving only error given below

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin>keytool -list -v -keystore 
 "C:\Users\kulde\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass 
 android -keypass android
 keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: 
 C:\Users\kulde\.android\debug.keystore
 java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: 
    C:\Users\kulde\.android\debug.keystore
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:742)
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:340)
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:333)
```

Comment: please follow my post :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `debug.keystore` which is less secure use your own created keyStore. [Follow this to do the same](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html)

After you created your keystore, run the following command in terminal of Android studio.

`keytool -list -v -keystore "path where .jks file is stored"`

After this terminal will ask for password which you have created in above step.

Finally you will get your SHA-1 certificate.

> Make sure you store your keystore safely. It will be used in future when you upload your App.

Comment: no need to go for .android you must have given different destination to your .jks file??

Answer (score 1):

[There is no debug.keystore in .android folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8576732/there-is-no-debug-keystore-in-android-folder)

The debug.keystore is created automatically on first build that uses it.

or

According to the documentation, performing a build in Eclipse or using ant debug should automatically generate ~/.android/debug.keystore.

But in case this doesn't work, you can create one manually by running:

keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -dname "CN=Android Debug,O=Android,C=US"

Comment: clean project. then rebuild project again. please

Comment: then check c folder destination.