# Can't retrieve SHA-1 key from Windows CMD line

Tags: android

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v \
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
```

This is the instructions from Google "Firebase in a weekend".  However this is not working.  I have tried to add my JRE to the path variable and have done ample research but I keep getting this error...

```
C:\>-alias androiddebugkey -keystore %CONNERGESBOCKER%\.android\debug.keystore
'-alias' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

thanks!

Comment: [Check this for solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44473434/6047274) hope it will help you.

Answer (score 4):

It's splitting it into two lines incorrectly.

Change the command to be a single line:

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
```

Comment: As a side note, to run it as 2 lines use the caret key (^) https://stackoverflow.com/a/69079/833647

Answer (score 0):

I found a easy way to get SHA-1

go to Gradle menu on right side of screen
then Task->android->SigningReport .
double click it.
after its complete you will see SHA-1 in the "Run" menu at botton(Scroll up to see it).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using android studio use simple step

1. Run your project
2. Click on Gradle menu
3. Expand Gradle task tree
4. Click on android-> signingReport and see the magic
5. It will tell you everything