# How to get the SHA-1 fingerprint certificate in Android Studio for release mode?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

My google map app works fine on device with debug google map API KEY but when I create signed apk for my app with release google map API KEY, it does not display map.
So what is the best way to display google map release on signed APK?
Please help

Comment: use keytool or add config in project setting

Comment: [You can the whole process in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44473434/6047274)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [debug.keystore not found inside c:\Users\kulde\.android∖](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44473328/debug-keystore-not-found-inside-c-users-kulde-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go in Google Console and Put Sha1 for relese apk

here is how to create sha1 for relese apk

**Run This Command in cmd/terminal**

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "your keystore path"
```

and add new sha1 for your relese apk

Answer (score 0):

In android studio when you create build for release, in android monitor you signed SHA key is shown.

Second option is using comand prompt cmd.
keytool -list -v -keystore ""