# Google sign for Signed apk in Ubuntu

Tags: android, google-signin

I have implemented google sign in for my app.It works fine for debug mode.I have refer [Google sign in signed apk not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36045652/google-sign-in-signed-apk-not-working) link and followed it but it has specified for MAc and Windows.I have Ubuntu OS. so for going to bin folder,i typed whereis java and got the following response from terminal

```
java: /usr/bin/java /usr/share/java /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz
```

Then i did

```
cd /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin
keytool -list -v -keystore /home/pritish/Desktop/simplypubliccloud.jks -alias key0
```

I got my SHA1 key and entered in Firebase Project Settings and downloaded the google services json file again and removed the old one from my project and added new one and rebuilded my signed apk & uploaded to play store,still i am not able to sign in using Google for signed apk.What am i doing wrong?
Please help

Comment: this link may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/44560658/8164071

Comment: I did the same thing