# debug.keystore is missing.can not find it in .androdid folder

Tags: android

Actually, Android Studio creates it automatically to the C/users/.android/.
.But when i check via signingReport,i face with these errors.

[image]

My .android file has no debug.keystore file

[image]

Ps:I am new for Android Programming.Could you tell me the simplest way to create android.keystore file ?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10981870/7746134

Comment: How to run this ? Could you tell me step by step?

(keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -dname "CN=Android Debug,O=Android,C=US")

Comment: Just copy paste that command in command prompt and run it.

Comment: I have  got  ( 'keytool is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file') error as you seen in the picture https://i.imgur.com/7R5ML1d.jpg

Comment: Add keytool to your path variable. Your keytool executable might be in `C:\Program Files\Java\jre\bin`

Comment: Thank you for help but when i click to keytool.exe (c/program files/java/jdk1.8.0_201/bin), command screen closes suddently, automaticly..

Comment: Clicking keytool.exe will close cmd. After adding keytool to your path, execute the command given in my first comment.