# Application is not installed error, when launched from home screen shortcut

Tags: android

FYI: I have gone through these links already
['App not Installed' Error on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226132/application-not-installed-error-on-android)

[Application not installed when i try to autoupdate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17299626/application-not-installed-when-i-try-to-autoupdate)

My question is little different.

- I released app with default/main activity as XActiivity.java in version 1.0
- I released update with changing default/main activity as YActivity.java
- I find that app opens fine from application meanu, but when I try to launch from home screen shortcut, it throws an error saying "**Application is not installed**"

I know that its due to shortcut referencing to old XActivity.java, by removing would solve this issue, but if I release app to thousands as an update  who already have this app would get annoyed at the first instance of this error message. I would loose on good reviews I got

Comment: Try removing the icon and creating a new shortcut.

Answer (score 28):

Please check if you have the property `android:exported="false"` on an activity that should have been a `"android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"`. This disables the specific activity from being launched on the launcher.

Comment: Android 12 requires activities [explicitly set this value](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#security). I set it to false originally, but changed it because of your answer. Thanks!

Comment: No it didn't, the doc applied it on a service. Just discern what is used as a launcher activity vs what is on a service so you would know where to apply the export attribute.

Comment: I linked the documented changes for Android 12 (API 31) above.

"If your app targets Android 12 and contains **activities**, services, or broadcast receivers that use intent filters, you must explicitly declare the android:exported attribute for these app components."

Comment: I looked more closely, it specifies that activities which use intent filters need the attribute. Since the Main/Launcher activity uses an intent filter, the attribute is required.

Comment: android:exported="true"  <= this fixed my issue.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer; so simple! Thanks @PierBetos!

Comment: This requirement (of course) also exists when debugging from Android Studio. I discovered this when upgrading an application that had been built in an older set of tools and then only to support up to Android 10.  The debugger messages in the IDE were a little different, about not finding the app. [Adding this comment essentially to inject "debugger" and "debugging" into the search results on the subject]

Answer (score 13):

in 2021,
just add

```
android:exported="true"
```

in the manifest, and it will be fixed

[image: Example]

Answer (score 4):

That is because homescreen shortcuts work slightly differently from the launcher icons in some launchers.

Your old shortcut still contains a reference to XActiivity as the main Activity, when you have updated it to be YActiivity. This causes Android to think the app isn't installed, as it cannot find an XActiivity in your app marked as the MAIN Activity.

Simply removing the home screen icon and adding it back will solve this.

Comment: Thank you, Yes I agree with /know your solution, but however if I release my update to thousands, its going to effect every one, so they might face same issue.

Comment: @Shri Unfortunately, there's not much you can do to get around it short of not changing your launcher class' name. Some launchers don't even have this problem, but a fair bit do. Its just one of those things you can't control.

Comment: Can anyone identify which launchers have this problem. I would like to be able to reproduce this.

Comment: omg I was thinking about an Android issue but it was just an Activity name update, such a stupid typo;)

Answer (score 3):

Putting

```
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

inside specific activity inside Manifest.XML did the job for me.

Comment: This is not connected to this problem. Documentation says Activity for shortcuts must be LAUNCHER and action MAIN. ( doc https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts)

Answer (score 3):

This question is old, but still relevant today.

This occurred because I changed the starting activity. I had this originally (truncated):

```
<manifest>
    <application>
        <activity android:name=".activities.StartActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.OtherActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I removed StartActivity but I forgot to remove android:exported="false", after adding the intent filter. It looked like this:

```
<manifest>
    <application>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.OtherActivity"
            android:exported="false"> <!-- REMOVE THIS -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

In short, make sure your starting activity is exported.

Answer (score 0):

What if you implement both XActivity and YActivity as entry points in your app?  XActivity could remove its launcher shortcut, install the YActivity shortcut, and launch YActivity.

Answer (score 0):

first ensure if current installed apps can be moved to sd card
if they cant be that is it you have got the reason
on my htc desire 300 while rooting i flashed wrong rom bricked my phone in bootloop
got it repaired from a shop
now running custom rom i dont know which one
but it doesnt support moving app to sd card 
so i copied app to phone memory
unmounted or removed sd card
then i try to install from phone memory and my fs2014 1.35 is now installed 
horrray
hope it help you
this will only work if you have custom rom because original rom does nt have errors like that
or you call that a bug

Comment: yeah but that works only if app not installed during app package installation

Answer (score 0):

Possible Solutions of “Application not Installed” error

- Reboot the phone: In times like this, first thing to do is to reboot
  your device. Or just shut down, remove and reinsert your battery.
- Make sure to uninstall any apps you don’t use to free up space, also 
  uninstall previous versions of the same app currently installed on
  your device.
- Double check the apk files you download and be sure they were
  completely copied or downloaded.
- Try resetting app permissions by going to Settings >Apps>All>Menu key

  > Reset application permissions or Reset app preferences.
- Change app installation location to Automatic or Let system decide.
  Make sure your SD card is not mounted or connected to a PC or
  elsewhere.
- For worst case scenarios, format your SD card – copy it’s contents
  somewhere else for backup and format.
- The last solution would be to totally wipe your device. Either by
  doing a factory reset under Settings or by doing a full wipe in
  recovery mode.

[Reference](http://mobilityarena.com/fix-application-not-installed-error-androids/)

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem, just a minute ago.
I'm not expert so all I could get from all answers is problem is in shortcut created on home screen by launcher.
I'm using classic minimalist launcher which doesn't have app drawer so all apps are on home screen, so I can't just delete shortcut without uninstalling it.

So I cleared cache of my launcher and it created new shortcut for that app on its own and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a case, check your code for "App shortcut creation" where the `Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT` is mapped to the LAUNCHER activity. (Might be SplashScreenActivity)

Answer (score -1):

The solution I wrote is.
**AndroidManfest.xml**

1. I retained intent filter  android.intent.action.MAIN for my previous XActivity.java.
2. I also retained intent filter android.intent.action.MAIN and also category as LAUNCHER to YActivity.java

In the onCreate() method of XActivity.java I added these lines, and it seems to have solved issue

```
Intent thisIntent = getIntent();
if(thisIntent.getAction() == "android.intent.action.MAIN"){

        Intent intent = new Intent(this,YActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
}
```

Comment: Hi - I am trying out your solution, but unfortunately this is really hard to test. Can you please explain how this fixes it, because if the problem is with the shortcut having a mismatched launcher activity embedded in its details then I'm not sure how this should resolve it. Please elaborate. Thanks!

Comment: This didn't fix it for me, but setting `android:exported="true"` did, as per this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39957428/1346778