# App isnt installed error

Tags: android, apk

I have been trying to run my app on my Nexus 4 for quite some time now. But everytime I try to launch it, it gives me an "App isnt installed" error. The app is working fine on the emulator. What could be the reason for this. Please help!

Comment: Hi, your question is a bit broad. Could you please try to specify and provide us with some more details? Like code for instance. That way it's easier for people to help you.

Comment: would my manifest code work?

Comment: @SwapnilHarkanth : "App isnt installed" error occur when you are using any user-feature or permission which not present on current device so try to check Manifest permissions

Comment: there are no permissions required in my app. after installing the app,the installer crashes as soon as i try to open it using the open button that is shown at the end of an installation. and when i try to run it from my apps screen, 'app isn't installed' toast is shown.

Answer (score 0):

After some research i have found that it is due to `YActiivity.`

`when you have updated it to be YActiivity. This causes Android to think the app isn't installed, as it cannot find an XActiivity in your app marked as the MAIN Activity.`

You can  solve it by removing home screen icon  and re establishing it back

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360731/application-is-not-installed-error-when-launched-from-home-screen-shortcut) for a more detailed info

Comment: Pleease have a look at the link i have given..I bet it will solve ur problem..Wht you need to do is to removing home screen icon  nd adding it once again

Comment: hey thanks for the link, but it was not what i was looking for. I am trying to open the app from my app screen and it isnt running, an 'app isnt installed' toast is showing up

Comment: http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-nexus/help/app-isnt-installed-error-phone-contacts-t1924845

Answer (score 0):

If you did any change to launcher activity in mainfest then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68515430/2828651) `android:exported="true"` could be the cause.

```
<activity 
android:name=".MainActivity"
android:exported="true">
```