# App isn't installed android error

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have installed android SDK 5.1 recently after that i am getting new errors which haven't seen before like App isn't installed error.Got this error if user clicks on app icon in device .Could you suggest how to fix this Here is my manifest code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.srikanth"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <!-- Internet permission -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />

    <application
        android:name="com.srikanth.utils.AppController"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.srikanth.SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/APP_ID" />

        <provider
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
            android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider1234"
            android:exported="true" />

        <activity android:name="com.srikanth.MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.srikanth.EditProfile" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.srikanth.UnlockActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.srikanth.FacebookFriends" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.srikanth.HomeActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.srikanth.SplashActivity" >
        </activity>
    </application>
```

and here is error report in console

```
  [2015-04-20 13:01:08 - InstaScene] Starting activity com.instascene.SplashActivity on device EBAZFG148859
    [2015-04-20 13:01:09 - InstaScene] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.instascene/.SplashActivity }
    [2015-04-20 13:01:09 - InstaScene] ActivityManager: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.instascene/.SplashActivity } from null (pid=8344, uid=2000) not exported from uid 10131
    [2015-04-20 13:01:09 - InstaScene] ActivityManager: at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1472)
    [2015-04-20 13:01:09 - InstaScene] ActivityManager: at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1426)
    [2015-04-20 13:01:09 - InstaScene] ActivityManager: at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerNative.java:2712)
    [2015-04-20 13:01:09 - InstaScene] ActivityManager: at com.android.commands.am.Am.runStart(Am.java:680)
    [2015-04-20 13:01:09 - InstaScene] ActivityManager: at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:270)
    [2015-04-20 13:01:09 - InstaScene] ActivityManager: at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:47)
    [2015-04-20 13:01:09 - InstaScene] ActivityManager: at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:76)
    [2015-04-20 13:01:09 - InstaScene] ActivityManager: at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
    [2015-04-20 13:01:09 - InstaScene] ActivityManager: at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:243)
    [2015-04-20 13:01:09 - InstaScene] ActivityManager: at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have checked this problem over stackoverflow and tried solutions but no luck here is reference links i have tried [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25956967/app-isnt-installed-error) [link2](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/issues/151)

Comment: In which targeted device you'r running your app??

Comment: Android 4.4.2 is device version

Comment: Have you set exported to true for activity?

Comment: yes i have tried it.

Comment: Is it android studio?? Change your target version from 21 to 19.

Comment: Ni ,I am using eclipse

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'r registering your `SplashActivity` twice.

```
<activity android:name="com.srikanth.SplashActivity" >
    </activity>

 <activity
        android:name="com.srikanth.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

So just need to remove one of them and add `android:exported="true"`

Comment: Yes Piyush ,I have declared same activity twice ,Thats the problem.Very blind mistake.Thanks for saving me.

Comment: It's very nice and glad to help you!! We can become a good developer after making some blind mistake !!!!

Answer (score 44):

Check to see if **android:exported** is set to **false** as per the security instruction given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67412314/5520787). If yes then you need to set it to **true** to test apps on your phone using USB debugging as shown here:

```xml
<activity 
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:exported="true">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```