# Dependency issues in navigation with Android Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

I am exploring compose navigation as specified in [the docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#groovy).

Adding the dependency with version `2.4.0-alpha07` as specified in docs, gives the following error,

**Error 1**

> One or more issues found when checking AAR metadata values:
>
> The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a dependency's AAR metadata
> (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties) is greater
> than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30). Dependency:
> androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.4.0-alpha07. AAR metadata
> file:
> /Users/abhimanyu/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/0575ff5712e0a9c15b8d7424501c07b8/transformed/jetified-navigation-compose-2.4.0-alpha07/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.

This error forces me to upgrade `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` of my app from 30 to 31.

Upgrading the version gives this error,

**Error 2**

> Manifest merger failed: Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android: exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

To solve that, checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67412084/manifest-merger-failed-apps-targeting-android-12-android-studio-error).

Even after adding the `android:exported`, I am getting the same error (error 2).

Is the `compileSdkVersion` upgrade to 31 mandatory?

If yes, how to solve Error 2. If no, how to solve Error 1?

I personally prefer to stick with SDK 30 if possible.

Comment: What makes you think you needed to upgrade your `targetSdkVersion`? That is not a requirement.

Comment: Ok. Got it. You are saying `targetSdkVersion` and `compileSdkVersion` need not necessarily be the same?

Comment: @Abhimanyu `minSdkVersion <= targetSdkVersion <= compileSdkVersion`. https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Now every AndroidX library released is compiled with API 31**.

You can check it also in the [Accompanist release notes](https://github.com/google/accompanist/releases/tag/v0.17.0):

> Accompanist is now built against SDK 31:
> **This means that your apps also need to compile against SDK 31**. This was necessitated by the latest AndroidX releases also being built against SDK 31.

Just use in your `build.gradle`

```
compileSdkVersion 31
```

but you should always compile with the latest SDK since it doesn't change your app behavior.
This has no bearing on your `targetSdkVersion`, you can continue to set that as you need.

The only rule is:

```
minSdkVersion <= targetSdkVersion <= compileSdkVersion
```

More details in the [doc](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd).

Comment: Fixing `targetSdkVersion` worked. Thanks!