# Android Studio - problem with kotlin script

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

On my first day of my kotlin journey I ran in to a problem. I really don't know Android Studio well so please if I didnIt express my question completely, ask me.

I'm learning through YouTube video Kotlin Android Tutorial | Learn How to Build an Android App. I Was able to create an Android simple app Hello world and run it on my PC and mobile phone, when I get to work with kotlin script problem occur:

> *Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs*
> 3x
> *android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for . Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined*

The app is working, but when I want to run just kotlin script I get errors.
Solution which I found here: [Manifest merger failed : Apps targeting Android 12 - Android Studio Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67412084/manifest-merger-failed-apps-targeting-android-12-android-studio-error)

Is not working for me. I tried lower the SDK but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify android:exported="false" or android:exported="true" in the AndroidManifest.xml file, in the manifests package. Bye bye Jason