# Can someone please check why this is giving me an error

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

[Manifest merger failed Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YDWv.png)

Comment: start reading [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16320675)

Comment: Why not do a simple search before creating a new question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/67412084/11880323

Comment: You need to put `exported="true"` inside the `<activity ...>` - see the [linked answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67412084/manifest-merger-failed-apps-targeting-android-12-android-studio-error) for examples of correct formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You should add in Manifest at Activity Main, `android:exported = "true"`
like this https://miro.medium.com/max/1338/1*eT0nvNesYdHi06LqV6m6mg.png