# apk install failed on android 12

Tags: android

```
compileSdkVersion 31
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 20
    targetSdkVersion 31
}
```

Build or assembly Debug works well.

However, "Problem parsing the package error" occurs when installing APK.

When I looked it up, I saw to add android:exported="true" to activity,
is it correct to add it to all activities?
Should I add something other than activities?

For example >> provider, receiver, service

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio error: "Manifest merger failed: Apps targeting Android 12"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67412084/android-studio-error-manifest-merger-failed-apps-targeting-android-12)

Comment: @cmak no, that's an entirely unrelated error that occurs at _build_ time, not install time.

Comment: "Manifest merger" errors are at build time. Please, post relevan `AndroidManifest.xml` code

Comment: The reason why I wanted to use sdkVersion 31 was because it was related to Android12 push
I couldn't solve the above problem and lowered it to sdkVersion 30.

Answer (score 2):

add android:exported="true" on activitys and services in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
 //set exported **true** for all activitys
<activity android:name=".SplashActivity"
              android:exported="true" />

<service
    android:name=".autofillservice.MyAutofillService"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_AUTOFILL">
```

Comment: I applied it to activity and service, but it still doesn't work. Is there anything else I need to check?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to use `Internal Testing` in the google play developer account, you can add your testers and you can get all benefits of google play features like the direction of deep links