# android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for <receiver>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher In Flutter

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for <receiver>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.
```

This Error is throwing in my Flutter app. I set `android:exported="true"` in all activities and services.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp">
    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />

    <application
        android:label="My APP"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon">

       <meta-data android:name="io.flutter.network-policy"
           android:resource="@xml/network_security_config"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/rsoft_logo" />
        <activity
            android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <meta-data
                android:name="flutterEmbedding"
                android:value="2" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:exported="true"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.MinWidth"
            android:name=".PopUpActivity"/>
        <receiver android:name=".CallReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IUAl.jpg)

Comment: Seems like the error is with the plugin you are using. Can you share the full error log?

Comment: Can `this`    [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67412084/android-studio-error-manifest-merger-failed-apps-targeting-android-12]  help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make

```
 android:exported="false"
```

in all activities, services, receivers except MainActivity

Answer (score 0):

please Check build.gradle file:

```
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.4.1"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:core:1.4.0"
```

And Simply can be edit receivers > exported: "false"
**Another Way:**

1.First of all set target sdk to 30

2.Then go to the merged manifest

3.Find if there’s any activity, service, receiver or provider that does not have android:exported set.Override all those entries and set their android:exported to true or false.

4.set target sdk back to 31 and run project