# When I install my application again then show Apps targeting Android 12 in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-manifest

[image]

How I fix this error
\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.app.kathana">
    <!-- The INTERNET permission is required for development. Specifically,
         the Flutter tool needs it to communicate with the running application
         to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>
```

build.gradle
[image]
How I fix it

**debug console**

D:\Working\Intern\Codes\Apps\kathana\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-33:20 Error:
android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$EmptyActivity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.
D:\Working\Intern\Codes\Apps\kathana\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:34:9-40:20 Error:
android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$EmptyFloatingActivity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you copy the debug console and paste it here?

Comment: The `androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$EmptyActivity` would need to be an `<activity>` entry in your manifest to add the `exported` flag manually. Either your test/build tools are not setup to support a target of Android 12 or you may have to clean and rebuild. Maybe https://github.com/android/android-test/issues/896 see if you can update those test libraries to a newer version

Comment: That's already added bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error . That's not "**android:exported="true"** " , I comment android build.gradle dependencies and run the project one by one. Finally I commented the "**implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:latest.release'**" this facebook dependencies then project worked prefect. But I want facebook dependencies for my project therefore I added newest dependencies " **implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:5.+'**"

Answer (score 1):

Since your application is targeting Android 12, please take a look at your `AndroidManifest.xml` and make sure to add this `android:exported`.

It's also answered here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/67412314/12862313 
 with further reading links.

Comment: all ready added bro i will edit this question and add image

Answer (score 0):

check app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/release/AndroidManifest.xml for  any activities that use  that do not have android:exported = true.

In my case I had to add these two lines in the main AndroidManifest.xml

Please note that I had this issue on React Native, not on flutter.

```
<activity android:exported="true" android:name="androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$EmptyFloatingActivity" android:theme="@style/InstrumentationActivityInvokerFloatingActivityTheme">       
    <intent-filter>            
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>      
    </intent-filter>        
    </activity>

    <activity android:exported="true" android:name="androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$EmptyActivity" android:theme="@style/InstrumentationActivityInvokerEmptyActivityTheme">        
    <intent-filter>      
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```