# Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` - andriod studio

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-sdk-tools

I've updated my SDK version to 31, afterward I get this error. this is my Gradle :

compileSdk 31

buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
defaultConfig {
applicationId "com.cima.cima4u1"
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdk 31
versionCode 60
versionName "3.5.0"
multiDexEnabled true
testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

than i got the error :

```
Error:
    android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for <activity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.
```

my manifast file as the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.cima.cima4u1"
    tools:ignore="MissingLeanbackLauncher">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" tools:node="remove"/>

    <application
        android:name="com.cima.cima4u1.utils.MyAppClass"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

        <activity android:name="com.cima.cima4u1.RazorPayActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.cima.cima4u1.SearchActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.cima.cima4u1.PapalPaymentActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Nobar" />
        <activity android:name="com.cima.cima4u1.WebViewActivity" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="@string/admob_application_id" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationOpened.DEFAULT"
            android:value="DISABLE" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.OPTIONS_PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME"
            android:value="com.google.android.exoplayer2.ext.cast.DefaultCastOptionsProvider" /> <!-- facebook -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"
            tools:replace="android:value" /> <!-- razorpay metadata -->
        <!--
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.razorpay.ApiKey"
            android:value="rzp_live_eHkQKgddhVS9ub"/>
        -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity> <!-- facebook end -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.cima.cima4u1.TermsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Nobar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.cima.cima4u1.ReplyActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_reply"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.cima.cima4u1.ProfileActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Nobar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.cima.cima4u1.PassResetActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Nobar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.cima.cima4u1.SearchResultActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Nobar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.cima.cima4u1.SignUpActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Nobar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.cima.cima4u1.LoginActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Nobar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.cima.cima4u1.DetailsActivity"
            android:configChanges="screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_details"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" /> <!-- android:configChanges="screenLayout|screenSize|orientation" -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.cima.cima4u1.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Nobar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.cima.cima4u1.SettingsActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Nobar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.cima.cima4u1.SplashScreenActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.cima.cima4u1.ItemMovieActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_item_show"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />


        <activity
            android:name="com.cima.cima4u1.ItemTVActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Nobar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.cima.cima4u1.ItemSeriesActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Nobar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.cima.cima4u1.SubscriptionActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Nobar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.cima.cima4u1.StripePaymentActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Nobar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.cima.cima4u1.PurchasePlanActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Nobar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.cima.cima4u1.DownloadActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Nobar" />

    </application>
</manifest>
```

```
i don't know honstly what i have to do to solve this one
```

Comment: Follow the answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/67412314/9854554

Answer (score 2):

Just add
`android:exported="true"` to your activities, like:

```
          <activity
            android:name="com.cima.cima4u1.TermsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Nobar"
            android:exported="true" />
```

Comment: THE SAME ERROR STILL APPEAR

Comment: Could you pleae paste here an error, better full error log to read it whole. thanks