# i am trying to export my project to my phone but it shows this error any solutions?

Tags: flutter

PS D:\chat app\chatapp_firebase\chatapp_firebase> flutter run
Launching lib\main.dart on CPH2363 in debug mode...
Parameter format not correct -
D:\chat app\chatapp_firebase\chatapp_firebase\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:15:9-22:20 Error:
android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <receiver#com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceive
r>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <receiver#com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNoti
> ficationBootReceiver>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

BUILD FAILED in 26s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             27.8s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

plz help me with what to do

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

Comment: Possible Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67412084/android-studio-error-manifest-merger-failed-apps-targeting-android-12

Answer (score 0):

Probably a duplicated question. You can read some [possible solutions here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68648841/4605422).

You can also go to the folder `android\app\build.gradle` and set the **miSdkVersion** and the **targetSdkVersion** to 30.

```
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 30
    targetSdkVersion 30
    ...
```

Comment: Not the best way to solve the issue

Comment: The link I provided has several solutions for the issue, I don't need to copy-paste them all for an upvote.
Anyway, the minSDKVersion 30 is a good way to bypass this issue. As long as it is lower than 31, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The error says

> Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an
> explicit value for android:exported

Add the below to your android manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver"
              android:exported="true">   
    </receiver>
```

The above sets the exported value for the local notification receiver. That should fix it.