# How to fix Xamarin Error in Visual Studio for Mac 8.10.25 (build 2) "Java SDK 11.0 or above is required when using $(TargetFrameworkVersion)v12.0

Tags: java, android, macos, visual-studio, xamarin

I'm getting this error in VS for Mac 8.10.25 (build 2):

> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Legacy.targets(252,5): error XA0031: Note: the Android Designer is incompatible with Java SDK 11.0: https://aka.ms/vs2019-and-jdk-11

I've seen some answers on Stack Overflow for Visual Studio for PC, but I haven't been able to understand and/or apply the answers for my Mac hardware and software.

Comment: The OP stated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67412084/android-studio-error-manifest-merger-failed-apps-targeting-android-12 Solved this issue. The question will be marked as a duplicate when the bounty expires.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio error: "Manifest merger failed: Apps targeting Android 12"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67412084/android-studio-error-manifest-merger-failed-apps-targeting-android-12)

Answer (score -2):

First, you need to verify which version of Java you have installed on your system.If you're indeed using Java 11.0, you should install an earlier version of Java that is compatible with the Android Designer. Historically, Android development has been most compatible with Java 8.

After installing the compatible version of Java, you may need to configure your system to use that version. This might involve updating the JAVA_HOME environment variable to point to the directory where the compatible Java version is installed.

Make sure that your Visual Studio for Mac is up to date. Sometimes, newer updates include fixes for compatibility issues.

Check your Xamarin.Android project settings within Visual Studio for Mac to ensure that it's using the correct Java version. You might need to specify the path to the compatible Java SDK in your project settings.

If there are any project files or configuration files where you can specify the Java SDK version, review them to ensure that the correct version is being used.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! When you write "Java 11.0", is that the same thing as Java SDK 11.0?  If so, the error message specifically says I need Java SDK 11.0 or above.

Comment: *When you write "Java 11.0", is that the same thing as Java SDK 11.0?* Yes.