# Unable to start application on shorcut home icon click

Tags: android

I have create shortcut icon on home of another application using code:

```
Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(context,
                        list.get(i).activityInfo.applicationInfo.name.getClass());
shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
Intent addIntent = new Intent();
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME,                            manager.getApplicationLabel(list.get(i).activityInfo.applicationInfo));
                addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
                Parcelable icon = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(context, R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, icon);
                context.sendBroadcast(addIntent);
```

I am unable to start that application on shortcut icon click on home.

Comment: what happens instead?

Comment: I don't see you calling `startActivity()` anywhere. You intend to open another application, yes? https://stackoverflow.com/a/2780475/5746918

Comment: @IshitaSinha, he doesn't need to I think. He is calling `context.sendBroadcast(addIntent);`

Comment: I want to start app on click of shortcut icon after create.

Comment: I am getting messsage "Application is not intalled" after click.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360731/application-is-not-installed-error-when-launched-from-home-screen-shortcut

try this link

Comment: I have already seen it but not help.

Comment: @user8269038 are you trying to launch the app from the home screen of the device or from a screen in another application? @VladMatvienko `sendBroadcast` only works if the activity in question has registered a receiver for such a broadcast.

Comment: try getting the launcher activity class instead of what you are getting

Comment: I am trying to launch the app from the home screen of the device.

Comment: @djvjvfvdfvhj Put a breakpoint and see what this returns: `list.get(i).activityInfo.applicationInfo.name.getClass()`. Or paste the logcat response on clicking the shortcut.

Comment: it means like LauncherActivity.class.