# For me, adding android:exported="true" does not solve the problem

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, manifest

> see this question [Application is not installed error, when launched from home screen shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360731/application-is-not-installed-error-when-launched-from-home-screen-shortcut/17361148)

AndroidManifest.xml :

```xml
<application
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppTheme">
        <activity
                android:name=".ui.activity.MainActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:exported="true"
                android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter
                    >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter
                    >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <data android:scheme="app" android:host="appname"
                />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <nav-graph android:value="@navigation/nav_graph_main"
                    />
        </activity>
</application>
```

Gradle [App] :

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

i'm get this error :

```
> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED
/home/mhrohani/IdeaProjects/PrjName/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml Error:
    android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for <receiver>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.
/home/mhrohani/IdeaProjects/PrjName/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml Error:
    android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for <receiver>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.


Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
```

Project and android studio configs :

```
Gradle :                 ** 7.1.1 **  
Android Gradle Plugin :  ** 7.0.0 **  
Android Studio Version : ** Arctic fox 2020.3.1 **  
OS :                     ** Linux Ubuntu **
```

I'm try rebuild and sync project but does not working.

Comment: `android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for <receiver>` – It's not really clear what your specific question is, but that message is saying that the error(s) are in a `<receiver>` element, not that `<activity>`.

Comment: im not have <receiver> tag in manifest xml

At first I thought it was navigation-component problem but after deleting it I got the same error again . in 
<nav-graph android:value="@navigation/nav_graph_main" />

Why did I act before receiving this error, considering that I put another question link, but instead of solving another problem?

im complete manifest file in question . see it .

Comment: Mouaad Abdelghafour AITALI , How do I fix the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note the error text

> android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for **receiver**

This means you have to look for **receiver** in main/dependencies manifest, if you find this tag on main manifest, you have to add the value of **android:exported** and if you can't find receiver tag inside the main manifest, then you should search inside other dependencies manifests, I will show you step by step

1- Open manifest file on Android Studio

2- At the bottom click on **Merged Manifest**

3- Open all the dependencies manifests in order and look for  that does not contain a **android:exported**

4- I'm sure this tag will be found, after finding it just copy the whole tag and add it in the main manifest, do not forget to add the value of **android:exported** to it

Example:

**receiver** tag inside one of dependencies manifest file:

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.moduletop.push.UserPresentBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Add this tag inside main manifest:

```
<receiver
        tools:node="merge"
        android:exported="false"
        android:name="com.moduletop.push.UserPresentBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Cafebazaar dependencies had created this problem . i called with them and it solved . thanks Mr. nadimi :)

Comment: Your welcome, you can use https://github.com/MrNadimi/CafeBazzarTools for Cafebazaar payments,